# jacoco plugin not working with sunfire plugin.. org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I want to use jacoco plugin to generate a site to show my coverage tests. But when i add the plugin to plugins it gives me org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException which does not appear when i dont use jacoco plugin.
Here is my pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>fr.umfds.agl</groupId>
<artifactId>couvertureEtMutation</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <junit-platform.version>5.7.0</junit-platform.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-platform.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-platform.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <!-- attached to Maven test phase -->
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I want my coverage reports to be generated in target / site / jacoco . I searched on internet and found many similar problems but none of the solutions worked for me. But to be more clear about the error i am getting this:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test 
(default-test) on project couvertureEtMutation: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\tanku\Documents\L3\Semestre1\HAI501I(GenieLogiciele)\tp4\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was cmd.exe /X /C "C:\Users\tanku\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_16.0.2.v20210721-1149\jre\bin\java -server -ea -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xmx4g -XX:-UseSplitVerifier ${surefire.argLine} -jar C:\Users\tanku\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire13202390967333438775\surefirebooter9706852401708371992.jar C:\Users\tanku\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire13202390967333438775 2021-12-04T13-02-20_823-jvmRun1 surefire13582094628762200674tmp surefire_04422354844095939650tmp"
[ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 1
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was cmd.exe /X /C "C:\Users\tanku\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_16.0.2.v20210721-1149\jre\bin\java -server -ea -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xmx4g -XX:-UseSplitVerifier ${surefire.argLine} -jar C:\Users\tanku\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire13202390967333438775\surefirebooter9706852401708371992.jar C:\Users\tanku\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire13202390967333438775 2021-12-04T13-02-20_823-jvmRun1 surefire13582094628762200674tmp surefire_04422354844095939650tmp"
[ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 1
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:669)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:282)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:245)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1183)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1011)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:857)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

adding configurations to sunfire plugin removed the error but did not help me to generate a site to see my coverage results.

```
<configuration>
    <argLine>-Djdk.net.URLClassPath.disableClassPathURLCheck=true</argLine>
</configuration>

<configuration>
    <forkCount>0</forkCount>
</configuration>
```

[Second result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPa6a.png)

Comment: The reason is this: `Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test 
(default-test) on project couvertureEtMutation: There are test failures.` Your tests are failing... you have to take a look into your tests which are failing...!

Comment: For some reason calling an external JVM with a surefirebooter.jar failed. Can you execute this command in the console and show us the output? `%USERPROFILE%\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_16.0.2.v20210721-1149\jre\bin\java -server -ea -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xmx4g -XX:-UseSplitVerifier ${surefire.argLine} -jar %LOCALAPPDATA%\Temp\surefire13202390967333438775\surefirebooter9706852401708371992.jar %LOCALAPPDATA%\Temp\surefire13202390967333438775 2021-12-04T13-02-20_823-jvmRun1 surefire13582094628762200674tmp surefire_04422354844095939650tmp`

Comment: @khmarbaise
All my junit tests are good, they are not failing. Would it help to show a screen shot of them?

Comment: @khmarbaise: In my opinion this does not concern the tests (as the poster writes, they execute fine when code coverage is not in play). I suspect a configuration problem somewhere and the real issue is that forking surefire fails: `Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log`

Comment: @roccobaroccoSC I put a screen shot to my post.

Comment: Then remove this option from the command: `-XX:-UseSplitVerifier` and try again.

Comment: I am edditing my post with the new result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same problem, following the same tutorial. Updating the JaCoCO plugin to 0.8.8 seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try if it works with my jacoco configuration?

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>pre-unit-test</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</destFile>
                <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>${project.build.directory}/classes/**/*Impl*.class</exclude>
                    <exclude>${project.build.directory}/test-classes/**/*.class</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>post-unit-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</dataFile>
                <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>${project.build.directory}/classes/**/*Impl*.class</exclude>
                    <exclude>${project.build.directory}/test-classes/**/*.class</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>${project.build.directory}/classes/**/*Impl*.class</exclude>
            <exclude>${project.build.directory}/test-classes/**/*.class</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I also have in `properties`:

```xml
<surefireArgLine />
<jacoco.version>0.8.2</jacoco.version>
```

Comment: It gives me:--- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.2:report (post-unit-test) @ couvertureEtMutation ---
[INFO] Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file.

Comment: I am quite puzzled by that. Which Maven version are you using? Do you execute your tests in Eclipse? If so, maybe try directly with maven from the command line: `mvn clean package` should execute your tests and the code coverage. At this point I am suspecting a configuration problem with Eclipse.

Comment: It does not give me build failure but not generating the site. I will put a screen shot of the whole result to my post.

Comment: I followed this [tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Jacoco/article.html) when setting up the code coverage with Maven. Try to create a completely new project with a single dummy test and then execute `mvn clean verify` from the command line. The code coverage reports should be found somewhere under `target`.

Comment: When the example works, you need to compare what is different with your project's `pom.xml`.

Comment: Yes i am using Eclipse to execute my tests. Normally i am right clicking on the project and doing run as -> maven build.. -> mvn clean test and the executing my tests after that to be sure. I did try clean package but it only did tests.

Comment: Try to run maven from the command line outside of Eclipse. We need to see if the problem is in your Maven configuration, or in Eclipse. If you don't have Maven for command line, you will need to install it.